# JProfiler : Finding the Memory leak reference name

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

I am trying to use JProfiler for one of my Application which is running under tomcat server .

So i wrote a memory leak servlet as shown below .

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "" })
public class Dust extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String str = new String();
    List myarrylist = new ArrayList();
    int i = 10;
        while (true) {
    myarrylist.add(str);
    System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Now When i ran JProfiler on this Application using the Profile Web Application running locally .
It gave me this view . please see the screen shot here

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2r5c2nq&s=7

I have these questions :

1. It shows that number of String Objects are being created .
   (But how can we know in what class / servlet  and exactly which string is actually responsible for this creation of objects , as we may have many Strings in a Application. ) ??
2. And why the Start Button ( which i highlited) is being disabled ??
3. Is starting JProfiler is sufficient by clicking on the start Button ( Please see that image ) , nd dont we need to start the Tomcat server also ??

Please help . Thank you .

Comment: Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the heap walker for that. The dynamic memory views cannot show any information about references because a snapshot has to be created.

Please see [this screen cast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/04/in-screencast-below-i-show-strategy-for.html) for more information on how to find a memory leak with JProfiler.