# Finding memory leak By JProfiler

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, jprofiler

My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862991/jprofiler-finding-the-memory-leak-reference-name) I've done profiling of my application it is too slow.
After completion of one process I have seen some live objects in the heap walker.

Though we are caching some data from database to `HashMap` but the heap walker shows me some live objects like `Resultset.getString` and `Statement.getString` which should not be there.

`HashMap.put()` taking very less memory then above two methods.

Have I done everything fine and is this analysis right? OR I am missing anything and the memory is occupied by `HashMap` itself and `HeapWalker` is just showing me methods of JDBC (`getString` and `executeQuery`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're talking about methods, I guess you're looking at the "Allocations" view of the heap walker. That view shows where *objects have been created*, not where *objects are referenced*. There's a screen cast that [explains allocation recording in JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/08/allocation-recording-explained.html).

`HashMap.put` will not allocate a lot of memory, it just creates small "Entry" objects that are are used to store key-value pairs. The objects that take a lot of memory are created before you put them into the hash map.

`Resultset.getString` and `Statement.getString` create the String objects that you read from your database. So it's reasonable to assume that some of these objects are longer-lived.

To find out **why** objects are still on the heap, you should go to the reference view, select incoming references and search for the "path to GC root". The "biggest objects" view is also very helpful in tracking down excessive memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Ingo I've been seeing u for the long time of providing the good answersrelated to JProfiler.. I was expecting the answer from you..  I have a quetion - Do these object(Resultset and Statement) should be there in the heap after your database process finished...?

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR no, they should not really be on the heap

Comment: just one more quetion, I am using hashmap to cache some data, it usually populate when we logged in. It populate perfectly but its size grows continuosly. When GC called its size decreased but after sometime it again strating increasing rapidly. Is it a memory leakage

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR yes, a cache that grows unbounded over time would be considered a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

What you may be seeing is cached data held by the connection (perhaps its buffer cache) or the statement or result set.

This could be through not closing the connection, statement or result set or it could be due to connection pooling. If you look at the memory profile, you may be able to see the "path to GC root" (the path to the object root) and this would indicate what is holding your `ResultSet` strings. You should see if it's in your code, cached within something you retain or if it's in a pool.

N.B. I've not used JProfiler but this is how I would track it with [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/).